# Laravel collection filter using scopes

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following table:

### Active

id
starts_at
ends_at

I would like to get all the actives daily, comparing the two dates starts_at and ends_at and get the diff in days, like this example:

```
Route::get('test', function(){
$dailyActives = \App\Models\Active::all()->filter(function ($active) {
   return $active->starts_at->diffInDays($active->ends_at) >= 1 && $active->starts_at->diffInDays($active->ends_at) <= 3;
});

dd($dailyActives);
```

});

it works 100%.

But I would like to reuse this code as I have more modes like Daily, Weekly, Month.

My idea was creating a scope in the model but I can't use filter as $query is not a collection.
I tried the following code:

```
/**
 * Scope a query to only include daily actives.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeDaily($query)
{
    $query->filter(function ($active) {
        if($active->starts_at->diffInDays($active->ends_at) >= 1 && $active->starts_at->diffInDays($active->ends_at) <=3) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

So can someone recommend me the best way to do that? Maybe using scope and how? or creating a reusable class, where just calling the Active::daily()->get() I get all the actives daily, for example.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: A lot of things aren't clear to me. What is model `Active`? Why does this model have a method called `daily` when there is also a model called `Daily`. What do they share in common or what is the difference between all of them? If `Active::daily()->get()` would be a plausible solution, does it mean that it would also work for `Daily::daily()->get()` and `Weekly::monthly()->get()`? Why is the model `Month` not called `Monthly`?

Comment: Or are you trying to get all `active` instances between a certain date/time from the models `Daily`, `Weekly` and `Month`? In other words this would result in `Daily::getActives()`, `Weekly::getActives()` and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use a filter. Use scop like this `$dailyActives = \App\Models\Active::interval('weekly')->get();`

```
public function scopeInterval($query, $interval = 'daily')
{
    // daily
    $dateBetween = [now()->startOfDay(), now()->endOfDay()];

    if($interval === 'weekly'){
        $dateBetween = [now()->startOfWeek(), now()->endOfWeek()];
    }
    elseif($interval === 'month'){
        $dateBetween = [now()->startOfMonth(), now()->endOfMonth()];
    }

    $query->whereBetween('created_at', $dateBetween);
    
    return $query;
}
```